# Matrix array algorithm logic in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, array-algorithms

I am trying to solve this algorithm in JavaScript. How can I write a solution considering time complexity, considering the maximum key value is 3?

```
input1 = [{0: "small"},{0: "large"}]
output1 = [ 'small.', 'large.']
-----------------------------------------
input2 = [ {0: "small"},{0: "large"}, {1: "red"} ]
output2 = ['small.red', 'large.red']
-----------------------------------------
input3 = [{0: "small"},{0: "large"}, {1: "red"}, {2:"cake"} ]
output3 = ['small.red.cake', 'large.red.cake'}
-----------------------------------------
input4 = [{0: "small"},{0: "large"}, {1: "red"}, {1: "orange"}, {2: "cake"} ]
output4 = ['small.red.cake', 'large.red.cake', 'small.orange.cake', 'large.orange.cake'}
------------------------------------------
input5 = [ {0: "small"},{0: "large"}, {1: "red"},{1: "orange"},{1: "blue"},{2: "cake"},{2: "ice"}]
output5 = ['small.red.cake', 'large.red.cake', 'small.orange.cake', 'large.orange.cake', 'small.blue.cake', 'large.blue.cake', 'small.red.ice', 'large.red.ice', 'small.orange.ice', 'large.orange.ice', 'small.blue.ice', 'large.blue.ice']
] //12 combinations
```

My attempt: I purposely checking the index in if condition. and it is working as expected. I'm looking for the best solution.

```
const input5 = [ {0: "small"},{0: "large"}, {1: "red"},{1: "orange"},{1: "blue"},{2: "cake"},{2: "ice"}]

 let array1 = [];
let array2 = [];
let array3 = [];
input5.forEach(val => {
  if(val[0]) {
    array1.push(val[0]);
  }
  if(val[1]) {
    array2.push(val[1]);
  }
  if(val[2]) {
    array3.push(val[2]);
  }
});
const finalArray = [];
array1.forEach(val1 => {
  if(array2.length > 0) {
     array2.forEach(val2 => {
       if(array3.length > 0) {
         array3.forEach(val3 => {
           const finalVal = `${val1}.${val2}.${val3}`;
           finalArray.push(finalVal);
         })
       }else {
         const finalVal = `${val1}.${val2}`;
         finalArray.push(finalVal);
       }
     })
  }else {
    const finalVal = `${val1}.`;
    finalArray.push(finalVal);
  }
})
console.log(finalArray);
```

Comment: Do you have an attempt at a solution? Dividing the values by level/depth and permutating over each level is basically all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @KelvinSchoofs i have been trying  from long time trying using foreach loops but that is not the right approach and also am not getting the result as expected. so finally came to stackoverflow looking for solution.

Comment: still a good idea to post your attempts. Either there's a bug we can point out, or if you're just using a wrong approach, we can suggest another approach.

Comment: i posted my attempt @KelvinSchoofs

Comment: Somehow this feels like recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach works, but whether it fits your time complexity requirements, I can't tell:

```js
const inputs = [
    [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }],
    [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }],
    [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 2: "cake" }],
    [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 1: "orange" }, { 2: "cake" }],
    [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 1: "orange" }, { 1: "blue" }, { 2: "cake" }, { 2: "ice" }],
];

function permutate(results, todo) {
    // If we have no layers left to go through, return the results
    if (!todo.length) return results;
    // Get first element of todo and store the rest for later
    const [layer, ...rest] = todo;
    // Flatmap that for example with:
    //   results = ['a', 'b']
    //   layer = [1, 2, 3]
    //  maps the results into:
    //    [ ['a.1', 'a.2', 'a.3'], ['b.1', 'b.2', 'b.3'] ]
    //  which will then be flattened together.
    results = results.flatMap(result => {
        return layer.map(value => `${result}.${value}`);
    });
    // After that, we permutate the rest of the layers
    return permutate(results, rest);
}

function getCombinations(input) {
    console.log('getCombinations for:', input);
    // Split per layer
    const layers = [];
    for (const obj of input) {
        for (const level in obj) {
            let layer = layers[level];
            if (!layer) layer = layers[level] = [];
            layer.push(obj[level]);
        }
    }
    // Now we have e.g. [ ['small', 'large'], ['red', 'orange'], ['cake', 'ice'] ]
    console.log('layers:', layers);
    // We immediately pass layer 0 as an array of results
    // then for every other layer, we build upon the (previous) results
    return permutate(layers[0], layers.slice(1));
}

for (const input of inputs) {
    console.log('========');
    const combs = getCombinations(input);
    console.log('combinations:', combs);
}
```

If your input was in a better format, that would be more performant and easier to code.

Answer (score 2):

You could build an array of arrays with values at the wanted index and get the Cartesian product of the formatted.

```js
const
    cartesian = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), [])),
    format = array => {
        const temp = array.reduce((r, o) => {
            Object.entries(o).forEach(([i, v]) => (r[i] ??= []).push(v));
            return r;
        }, []);

        while (temp.length < 2) temp.push(['']);
        return temp;
    },
    fn = data => cartesian(format(data)).map(a => a.join('.'));

console.log(fn([{ 0: "small" },{ 0: "large" }]));
console.log(fn([{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 1: "orange" }, { 2: "cake" }]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the shortest solution it is working for input5 but not working for input1. I will modify it. Appreciate.

Comment: @Trinu, what if you have no objects in the array? please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly concise solution grouping by key and then using a modified zip on the first two elements of the result until only one element remains then flat() and return.

```js
function getOrderedPermutations(arr) {
  const combine = (a, b) => a.flatMap(a_ => b.map(b_ => `${a_}.${b_}`));

  let grouped = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, o) => (
    Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => (a[k] ??= []).push(v)), a), {})
  );

  let i = grouped.length - 1;
  while (i--) {
    const [a, b, ...rest] = grouped;
    grouped = [combine(a, b), ...rest];
  }

  return grouped.flat();
}

const inputs = [[{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }], [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }], [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 2: "cake" }], [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 1: "orange" }, { 2: "cake" }], [{ 0: "small" }, { 0: "large" }, { 1: "red" }, { 1: "orange" }, { 1: "blue" }, { 2: "cake" }, { 2: "ice" }],];

// Log tests
for (const input of inputs) {
  console.log('---');
  console.log('Input: ', input.map(o => `[${Object.entries(o)[0]}]`).join(', '));
  console.log('---');
  console.log(getOrderedPermutations(input), '\n');
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```